# how to copy some values of a row from a table to an other table?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

table 1 : users_infos (id, name, tel, email, fax, ...)
table 2 : users (id, name, tel)

table 2 is like table 1 but has only 3 informations

How can I copy a row from table 1 to table 2 where id =1 ?

I have used this code but not work :

```
insert users select id, name, tel from users_infos where id=1;
```

and like that not work too :

```
insert users select id, name, tel from users_infos where users_infos.id=1;
```

other problem, the table 2 has no icons for editing :
[like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXqrH.jpg)

Comment: If in doubt **RTFM** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like that :

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name, tel)
SELECT id, name, tel
FROM   users_infos
WHERE  id = 1
```

Comment: it works, thanks. but a smal problem:
the created table is nit editable !!! I it has no symbols for editing like table one.
I have made an test, i get the same problem. the table one is OK but table2 hasno icons !!!

Comment: What do you mean by icons ?

Comment: Please provide more details (where does this screenshot came from ? what is wrong ?)

Comment: I have fixed the problem, after i have made the id in table2 as Primary-key